# Why can I still zoom viewport in iOS 7

Tags: html, ios, ios7, safari, meta

I have tried these codes... but none of them work with safari in iOS 7...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

This used to work, does iOS 7 ignore this now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was preventing it from zooming...

I removed this code:

```
<script>
    if (window.screen.height<568) { 
        document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").content="width=320.1";
    }
</script>
```